# Cocos2dx : Falling Physics Ball passes through stage

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cocos2d-x, game-physics

If I move stage then ball passes through stage...if stage not moved then ball never pass through stage..How to set ball to not pass through ?

Here is Code:

```
ball->addComponent(PhysicsBody::createCircle(ball->getContentSize().width*0.5f, PhysicsMaterial(10.0f,0.1,0.1)));
ball->getPhysicsBody()->setGravityEnable(true);
ball->getPhysicsBody()->setRotationEnable(false);
ball->getPhysicsBody()->setDynamic(true);
ball->getPhysicsBody()->setTag(BALL_BODYS_TAG);
ball->getPhysicsBody()->setCategoryBitmask(0x01);
ball->getPhysicsBody()->setCollisionBitmask(0x02);
ball->getPhysicsBody()->setMass(10);
```

stage:

```
stage->addComponent(PhysicsBody::createBox(stage->getContentSize(), PhysicsMaterial(100.0f,0.1,0.1)));
stage->getPhysicsBody()->setGravityEnable(false);
stage->getPhysicsBody()->setTag(STEPS_BODYS_TAG);
stage->getPhysicsBody()->setMass(100);
stage->getPhysicsBody()->setDynamic(true);
```

stage Moving Code:

```
void GBStage::updateStage(float dt)
{
    Vec2 pos = this->getPosition();

    pos.y += sBridge->gameSpeed;

    this->setPosition(pos); //Updating just sprite position

}
```

Now stage moving upwards, ball falling down. But ball passes through stage. How to stop over stage. Whats wrong with my code ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Found temporary solution**. Now I stoped moving stages sprite position. I used setVelocity to move stages. Now ball never passthrough steps.

```
this->getPhysicsBody()->setVelocity(sBridge->steps_Velocity);
```

But in Cocos2d-ObjC with Box2D we had options to move sprite position and set sprite position to physics body. Now in Cocos2d-x we can't move sprite and set its position to body. If any one know is it possible to set sprite position to physics body and still achieve movement with sprite then please answer.